# How do I set the background color of a grouped UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want conjoined email & password textfields like so -

[image]

See how both the fields are nicely rounded & the background color is blue.

The way I have implemented this is to create a custom tableViewCell with a label and a text field in a grouped table view probably with a single section and two rows one of which is for username and other for password.

What I have got is below. I have come close to implementing this but I am getting a weird grey background. How do I get rid of this grey background?

[image]

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To remove gray background:

`tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];` in `viewDidLoad`

or  if above code doesn't work try this.

```
tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Answer (score 6):

I accomplish this with two lines:

```
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.tableView.backgroundView = nil;
```

Depending on the opacity you want you can also make sure of this:

```
self.tableView.opaque = NO;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

If you are using Interface Builder make sure you setup and connect your outlet for the `tableView`

You may want to call this method in `viewDidLoad:`

Comment: +1 for mentioning the `viewDidLoad`. In complex view hierarchy the table will ignore any background property changes.